# Python Json Parsing WildCards/Regex

Tags: python, json, regex, api

I am new to python and playing around with an exchange rate API.

I have been able to pull data and parse it successfully. The issue that I am having is with dates. What I am trying to do is pull down all currency rates using `https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2018-01-01&end_at=2018-09-01` and then split this out based on certain days.

I understand the structure of the data but I dont know how to parse anything passed `[rates]` as the date changes for each day.

Is there some way I can parse out the data for each specific day or even to ignore the day and just pull out all the `ILS` values from the json by something like `ILS_val = parsed["rates"][SOMEWILDCARD]["ILS"]` where SOMEWILDCARD will allow me skip all the dates and extract all the euro exchange rates

This is what I have so far

```
from urllib import *
import json

url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2018-01-01&end_at=2018-09-01&symbols=ILS,JPY"

thepage = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
parsed = json.loads(thepage)

rates = parsed["rates"]

file = open("currencyRates.txt", "w+")

for rate in rates.items():

    file.write(str(rate) + "\n")

file.close()
```

Comment: You need to adjust the url. With the one specified you do not get any `EUR` values. Additionally, consider using `with open(...)` (but this has nothing to do with the question, really).

Comment: I'm no Python expert but it sounds like you need to loop `rate`. Something like `for items in rate` and then you should be able to use `items["CAD"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over your items:

```
# Getting the values: day[0] for dates & day[1] for values
rates = [day[1]['JPY'] for day in parsed["rates"].items()]

# Write into file
with open("currencyRates.txt", "w+") as file:
    [file.write(str(rate) + "\n") for rate in rates]
```

Comment: Thats the ticket, am i right in saying that day becomes an array of all the items in rates? and that position [0] is going to be date and [1] the value? so loop though all items and take out the value and write it in the file?